# How to migrate Ingres database with tables, relationships along with data to MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, ingres

I would like to know the best way to migrate Ingres database completly with tables, views, relationship along with data to MS SQL Server using any Windows application. If not possible is there any tools that provide this feature along with Ingres procedure. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If data import task in MS SQL Server Management Studio doesnt work, and You dont want to put Your hands in dirty csv's then You should consider creating Integration Services Project and get source data from Ingres via OLEDB and push it in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Any migration tool for Microsoft(R) SQL Server(TM) that can connect to source database via ODBC, or a tool that can utilize Microsoft(R) .NET Data Provider supplied by Actian, will be able to move data to the MS SQL Server database.
More about Ingres .NET Data provider: http://community.actian.com/w/index.php/DOT_NET_DataProvider
More about Ingres ODBC: http://community.actian.com/wiki/Ingres_Articles#ODBC
On the last link you may find information how to get data from an Ingres database into your Excel spreadsheet, and more.