# Ingres to SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, ingres

Don't know if anyone can help but i have been tasked with getting all the information out of an Ingres DB into a SQL Server DB. I have virtually no experience of Ingres apart from fumbling my way through looking at what it does and how it does it.

Ideally, what i would like to do is create a linked server (if possible) on a SQL Server and query the data that way. has anyone done this in the past previously and if so, any guidance/help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This is too broad a topic for this forum, I'm afraid. Interesting challenge, though.

Comment: Suggest you use ssis as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887141/how-to-migrate-ingres-database-with-tables-relationships-along-with-data-to-ms). Alternatively search for an appropriate driver to create a linked server.

Comment: I've no knowledge of SQL server, but if it allows creation of ODBC links then installing an Ingres client would provide its ODBC driver so you could set up a data source to access a remote Ingres instance.

Answer (score 0):

You're got two choices ODBC or the Ingres .NET Data Provider. I suspect the Ingres .NET Data Provider is more capable, but you may find ODBC meets your requirements.

The Ingres .NET Data Provider requires the Data Access Server process (iigcd) to be running in your Ingres installation.

https://docs.actian.com/ingres/11.0/index.html#page/Connectivity%2FConnectivity_Title.htm%23

What version of Ingres are you running?